# How to do single click handler for active class?

Tags: jquery

Let's say,

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="main-sectors">
           <a href="#" class="sector-active">Name1</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name2</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name3</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name4</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name5</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Here, how can I apply `class="sector-active"` for each `a` element when click on it ?

Comment: Please post some effort. It is not hard if you read the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```js
$('.main-sectors a').click(function(){
 $('a').removeClass('sector-active');
 $(this).addClass('sector-active');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
       <div class="main-sectors">
           <a href="#" class="sector-active">Name1</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name2</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name3</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name4</a>
           <a href="#" class="p-l-35">Name5</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: then, previous clicked is still active.

Comment: @AbhiJA - that was not part of the description of your issue

Comment: @Rahul, yes yes, now its working.

Comment: Accept the answer and upvote for others . Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sad... I got minus mark

Comment: No worries mate

Comment: @AbhiJA - for showing ZERO effort. The google search I posted for you has a page full of duplicates. Be happy I closed it as duplicate or you would have had many more downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    $("a").addClass("sector-active");
});
```